# Crash in [NSApplication _crashOnExeption]

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm getting a crash (backtrace below) while my window is loading. It seems to suggest that something is happening with Core Animation, but I'm not initiating any animations, just showing the window.

Changing a particular stack view's clipping resistance from 1000 to 750 avoided the crash for a little while, but now it's back, though it happens at a different point now.

I tried to create a simplified version of my layout to demonstrate the issue here, but I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. So all I can do is refer you to the full app: https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/tree/0b70352239b6fbaba6d26c952ce6de4f111a5346

Crash backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007fff4339c454 in -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] ()
#1  0x00007fff43968cb1 in __65+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayRefresh]_block_invoke ()
#2  0x00007fff45af4417 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#3  0x00007fff45af433f in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#4  0x00007fff45ad68b8 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#5  0x00007fff45ad6153 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#6  0x00007fff44dc0d96 in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#7  0x00007fff44dc0a0f in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#8  0x00007fff44dc0884 in _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter ()
#9  0x00007fff43071a73 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#10 0x00007fff43807e34 in -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#11 0x00007fff43066885 in -[NSApplication run] ()
#12 0x00007fff43035a72 in NSApplicationMain ()
#13 0x0000000100005794 in main at /Users/i58922/Developer/Personal/Xit/Xit/main.m:5
#14 0x00007fff6d91d015 in start ()
#15 0x00007fff6d91d015 in start ()
```

What are the likely culprits in this situation? How can I narrow it down? It's a somewhat complicated window with nested split views and such.

Answer (score 8):

I finally narrowed it down to the fact that I was calling `tableView.view(atColumn:,row:,makeIfNecessary:)` with a row index out of bounds. This was causing an exception which then unwound the stack to an unrecognizable point before crashing.

I would have found it faster if I had turned on my "All Objective-C Exceptions" breakpoint, which should have been the obvious thing to do since it was crashing in `[NSApplication _crashOnException:]`.